# What are the differences between the Stack Exchange iOS and Android apps?

Tags: discussion, android-app, ios-app, mobile-app

Are there any differences between the Stack Exchange app on iOS and Android, or should they be considered functionally identical?

Are there any features one has that the other does not?

Comment: In a nutshell: the iOS app got like 10 times more features than the android app, because it has an active developer working on it, fixing its bugs, and adding new features. The android app has no single developer working on it for over a year now, so no new features, no bug fixes etc.

Comment: @ShadowWizard If you post that as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: Well, it's more a rant in its current form, I'll have to collect facts and examples to make it an answer... need time, might do it at some point if others won't do it in the meanwhile. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't think that saying the truth could be rant, particularly if it is tuned to be the possible least annoying for anybody. And your comment is very useful (it explains, why is it a better feeling to prefer the mobile site).

Answer (score 1):

As noted by [Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/shadow-the-welcoming-wizard) in [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295367/what-are-the-differences-between-the-stack-exchange-ios-and-android-apps#comment958185_295367):

> In a nutshell: the iOS app got like 10 times more features than the android app, because it has an active developer working on it, fixing its bugs, and adding new features. The android app has no single developer working on it for over a year now, so no new features, no bug fixes etc.